# Use jQuery to show links on hover

Tags: jquery, css

Desired Result: I would like to see hidden text (a set of links) for only the table row I am currently hovering over.

The problem: I am seeing the links for every row that contains the id blog_title (as expected with this particular code).

Here's my current code snippet:

```
$("td:has(#blog_title)").hover(function () {
            $('.hidden').show();
        }, function () {
            $('.hidden').hide();
        });
```

I feel like I am missing something simple here. I'm learning jQuery (very slowly, as I rarely use it) and would appreciate a push in the right direction. I'm thinking I need to use $(this) in there somewhere but I'm unsure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [jQuery find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method (or [children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) if the `.hidden` elements are just direct children of the table rows):

```
    $("td:has(#blog_title)").hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.hidden').show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.hidden').hide();
    });
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was needing! I appreciate your input

Answer (score 1):

That can actually be achieved using CSS. Something like

```
table tr .hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

table tr:hover .hidden {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

That way you avoid the need for jQuery and you can even add transition effects for opacity. That's why I didn't use `display: none` / `display: block`.

Comment: This is something that I refer back to regularly. I really appreciate you taking time to answer this question. Sorry for the (very) delayed comment!